SDL3's SDL_SetWindowModalFor() fails with "that operation is not supported" on Windows?
Here is the minimal code to test:
SDL_Window* parent = SDL_CreateWindow("Parent", 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
if (parent)
{
    SDL_Window* child = SDL_CreateWindow("child", 150, 200, 0);
    if (child)
    {
        int returnValue = SDL_SetWindowModalFor(child, parent);
        if (returnValue < 0)
        {
            SDL_Log(SDL_GetError());
        }
    }
}

SDL_GetError() returns:

That operation is not supported.

I am coding in Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11, using SDL2 and then testing latest version of SDL3.
Does anyone know if the problem comes from Windows or if it has already been asked anywhere?
EDIT It happens both with SDL2 and SDL3.

Looks like it's not supported for Windows yet: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/9427

Which makes sense, I was very surprised because the idea of making a window modal after creation is a bit odd.

Known issue: SDL_SetWindowModalFor isn't wired up for several platforms... 
